# Node.js - How to retrieve the value from an array?

Tags: node.js

```
var date = {

"1/2/20":500,
"2/2/20":601,
"3/2/20":702,
"4/2/20":803,
"5/2/20":904

}
```

How do I get only the number so it prints without the date like so:

```
500
601
702
803
904
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```
var date = {

  "1/2/20":500,
  "2/2/20":601,
  "3/2/20":702,
  "4/2/20":803,
  "5/2/20":904

}

console.log(Object.values(date))
```

```
➜  ~ node foo.js
[ 500, 601, 702, 803, 904 ]
```

If you want to match output exactly add a call to join.

```
console.log(Object.values(date).join('\n'))
```

```
➜  ~ node foo.js
500
601
702
803
904
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
let date = {

"1/2/20":500,
"2/2/20":601,
"3/2/20":702,
"4/2/20":803,
"5/2/20":904

}

for (let key of Object.keys(date)) {
    let val = date[key];
    console.log(val) 
}
```